# Jquery HTML Select tag append repeats itself

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have the following jquery script which is supposed to append option data to a select tag in html :

The function works very well and it appends data to the  select tag but it does not empty the select tag with the previous loaded information when the function runs. How can I empty the select tag and append new data afresh and also include the please select option tag ?

```js
setInterval(function() {
  get_client_list();
}, 3000);

function get_client_list() {
  client_list = '';
  $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "<?php echo base_url(); ?>operations/get_client_lists",
    dataType: "JSON",
    success: function(response) {
      $('#select_client_name').empty();
      client_list = '<option>Please select : </option>';
      for (i = 0; i < response.length; i++) {
        client_list += '<option value="' + response[i].id + '">' + response[i].name + '</option>';
        $('#select_client_name').append(client_list);
      }


    },
    error: function(response) {

    }
  });

}
```

Comment: You can call empty() on an element to remove all children.

Comment: Remove the interval and add this to your success. `setTimeout(get_client_list,3000)` - Using interval with Ajax has unexpected side effects. 
I do however not understand why the user only will have 3 seconds to select something and then you will kill it?

Answer (score 3):

Hope this code will help you..

HTML:

```
<select name="" id="select_client_name">

</select>
```

Your function with some changes:

```
function get_client_list() 
{
      client_list = '';
      $.ajax({
      type: "GET",
      url: "<?php echo base_url(); ?>operations/get_client_lists",
      dataType: "JSON",
      success: function(response) 
      {
          client_list +='<option value="">Please select : </option>';
          $('#select_client_name').prop('selectedIndex',0);
          for (i = 0; i < response.length; i++) 
          {
              client_list += '<option value="' + response[i].id + '">' + response[i].name + '</option>';
          }
          $('#select_client_name').html(client_list);
      },
      error: function(response) 
      {
         // code here
      }
   });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your problem arise from the usage of `.append()` within the `for` loop. It will append same options multiple times.

Generate `options` list completely then use `html()` to set options.

```
//Generate client_list 
var client_list = '<option>Please select : </option>';
for (i = 0; i < response.length; i++) {
    client_list += '<option value="' + response[i].id + '">' + response[i].name + '</option>';
}

//Set select with new generated options
$('#select_client_name').html(client_list);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
   setInterval(function () {
                get_client_list();
            }, 3000);

            function get_client_list() {
                client_list = '';
                $.ajax({
                    type: "GET",
                    url: "<?php echo base_url(); ?>operations/get_client_lists",
                    dataType: "JSON",
                    success: function (response) {
                   $('#select_client_name').html('');//this much change is needed
                        $('#select_client_name').empty();
                        client_list = '<option>Please select : </option>';
                        for (i = 0; i < response.length; i++) {
                            client_list += '<option value="' + response[i].id +        '">' + response[i].name + '</option>';
                            $('#select_client_name').append(client_list);
                        }


                    },
                    error: function (response) {

                    }
                });

            }
```

Answer (score 0):

You code looks fine, you are calling `empty`, the only thing you can do faster is to append the options one time to the DOM.

Code:

```
success: function (response) {
    $('#select_client_name').empty();
    var client_list = '<option>Please select : </option>';
    for (i = 0; i < response.length; i++) {
        client_list += '<option value="' + response[i].id + '">' + response[i].name + '</option>';
    }
    $('#select_client_name').append(client_list);
},
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/IrvinDominin/as2bcpz8/